# overwriting html input field value

Tags: angular

I'm new with angular and I'm trying to restrict possible values in a number input field.

I want the values to be above 0 and to never show any other value within the field.

I tried doing this by setting min parameter but that only works for the arrows. I still can insert the value manually (eg. typing -10).

I am able to override the value within the component, but the input field still shows invalid value.

How can I overwrite the input field value when I detect that there is wrong input?

For example: I type in -10, and the input field immediately shows 1.

html code:

```
<p>
  <input type="number" [ngModel]="numberValue" (ngModelChange)='onInputChange($event)' 
   min=1>
</p>
```

component code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})


export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
    numberValue:number = 1;
    ngOnInit(){
    }
    onInputChange(value:number){
    this.numberValue = Math.max(1,value);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML code.

```
<p>
  <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="numberValue" (ngModelChange)='onInputChange($event)' 
   min=1>
</p>
```

Use both bracket and parentheses with ngModel like this `[(ngModel)]="numberValue"`

Angular class.

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})

export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  numberValue: number = 1;

  constructor(private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  ngOnInit() { }

  onInputChange(value: number) {
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
    this.numberValue = Math.max(1, value);
  }
}
```

use `ChangeDetectorRef` to update ngModel.

Comment: Worked as a charm. Just one little question: afaik the [(ngModel)]="numberValue" is equal to [ngModel]="numberValue" (ngModelChange)="numberValue = $event". So what exactly does [(ngModel)]="numberVaue" (ngModelChange)=onInputChange($event) does differently from [ngModel]="numberValue" (ngModelChange)=onInputChange($event)?

Comment: I did read the article and found another thread that better articulates my question [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11234). Since I consider this to be another question than what I asked originally, I mark this as solved. Thanks!

Comment: I noticed if I use [ngModel]="numberVaue" (ngModelChange)=onInputChange($event) instead of [(ngModel)]="numberVaue" (ngModelChange)=onInputChange($event) the input value is not updated properly to the value that I modified inside the onInputChange function.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have misspeled the syntax of **[(ngModel)]** (banana in the box). So you need to update your **html** file like this:

```
<p>
  <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="numberValue" (ngModelChange)='onInputChange($event)' 
   min=1>
</p>
```

In your component **ts** file, you can access the value of the `$event` passed into the `onInputChange()` function like this:

```
onInputChange(event){
    this.numberValue = Math.max(1,event.target.value);
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your html and typescript file also as shown below 
**In HTML**

```
<p> <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="numberValue" (keyup)='onInputChange($event)' min=1></p>
```

**In Typescript**

```
onInputChange(e){
this.numberValue = Math.max(1,e.target.value);
  }
```

Comment: That works almost as I need it to but I can't delete the whole number and type a new one. Deleting the last digit always overwrites it immediately to 1. Is there a way to prevent this?